# why angular material design get rid of date picker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design, uidatepicker, angular-material

It makes sense to use mobile default date picker, but how to get a consistent date picker on a regular web application when using material design?

angular material design website(no picker):
https://material.angularjs.org/#/

google material design website(has picker):
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/pickers.html

Comment: Totally agree, they don't have lot of features in angular-material like [data tables](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html)

Comment: The library is still pre-1.0, so there are definitely gaps in functionality.  The date-picker and data tables are both being worked on.

Comment: Why use SO to complain about features in a project, surely this would be better off in the repository issue list https://github.com/angular/material/issues

Answer (score 7):

The library is still in development. Current version is 0.10.0.

You can check their [milestones](https://github.com/angular/material/milestones). The datepicker is scheduled for the next version (0.11.0) and it's been worked on in the branch wip(calendar)and discussed in this [thread](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/648).

Comment: so it is live and still no resolution

Answer (score 3):

I have the some problem and finally got the solution in the latest release of Angular Material that is 0.11.0-RC1

You can get an ovriew of code below:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="sliderdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <br>
  <br>
  <md-content style="margin: 16px; padding:16px">
     <h4>Start Date</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="endDate" md-placeholder="Enter start date"></md-datepicker>
    <br>
    <h4>End Date</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="startDate" md-placeholder="Enter end date"></md-datepicker>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

---

My Controller

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
      //do what you want here
});
```

---

you can currently use below link to get datepicker in angular material

https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/angular/bower-material/v0.11.0-rc1/angular-material.css

https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/angular/bower-material/v0.11.0-rc1/angular-material.js

or check my code in codepen

http://codepen.io/ankur-tiwari/pen/bVNEKJ

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while using md-datepicker. It got resolved later. Earlier i was using version 0.9.4 but when i used version 0.10.1 it worked. Try changing the Version to latest.